# How to slice a very long string in python

Tags: python, string

I need to slice a very long string (DNA sequences) in python, currently I'm using this:

```
new_seq = clean_seq[start:end]
```

I'm slicing about every 20000 characters, and taking 1000 long slices (approximately)

it's a 250MB file containing a few strings, identified each one with an id, this method is taking too long.
The sequence string comes from biopython module:

```
def fasta_from_ann(annotation, sequence, feature, windows, output_fasta):
    df_gff = pd.read_csv(annotation, index_col=False, sep='\t',header=None)
    df_gff.columns = ['seqname', 'source', 'feature', 'start', 'end', 'score', 'strand', 'frame', 'attribute']
    fasta_seq = SeqIO.parse(sequence,'fasta')
    buffer = []
    for record in fasta_seq:
        df_exctract = df_gff[(df_gff.seqname == record.id) & (df_gff.feature == feature)]
        for k,v in df_exctract.iterrows():
            clean_seq = ''.join(str(record.seq).splitlines())
            if int(v.start) - windows < 0:
                start = 0
            else:
                start = int(v.start) - windows
            if int(v.end) + windows > len(clean_seq):
                end = len(clean_seq)
            else:
                end = int(v.end) + windows
            new_seq = clean_seq[start:end]
            new_id = record.id + "_from_" + str(v.start) + "_to_" + str(v.end) + "_feature_" + v.feature
            desc = "attribute: " + v.attribute + " strand: " + v.strand
            seq = SeqRecord(Seq(new_seq), id=new_id,description = desc)
            buffer.append(seq)
            print(record.id)
    SeqIO.write(buffer, output_fasta, "fasta")
```

Maybe there's a more memory-friendly way to accomplish this.

Comment: You'll need a bit more info if you want people to properly help, like how many slices are you doing, are they all the same length, are they one after another or at various points, etc

Comment: I'll update the description

Comment: Not sure if it'll help or not (not tried it myself), but you could try reading the file in parts. Instead of `string = file.read()`, and `slice=string[0:20000]`, you could just read the required parts of the file. Each time you go `file.read(20000)`, it'll get the next 20k characters from the file, and doesn't require it all to be stored in memory.

Comment: It's hard to help unless you can show a complete code sample that demonstrates the issue. There are way too many possible causes of slowness lurking in the code that you haven't shown us. Have you profiled to be sure that it's the slicing that's taking the time?

Comment: FWIW, `s = 'x'*250*10**6; slices = [s[n:n+1000] for n in range(0, len(s), 20000)]` is pretty much instant on my machine. There's almost certainly something else going on that you're not showing us.

Comment: @MarkDickinson same here

Comment: @MarkDickinson a full example is provided now

Comment: So if you throw out everything from the `if int(v.start) - windows < 0:` line onwards, what effect does that have on the timing? I suspect that most of the time is being spent in `clean_seq = ''.join(str(record.seq).splitlines())`, but that's a guess: given an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can help. Alternatively, you need to profile to identify the slowness. I recommend Robert Kern's [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) package for line-by-line profiling.